# How to restart an app monitored by monit at specific time

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, monit

I have long-running python app which is monitored by monit, checking if all is well each minute. This is great, however, if the app misbehaves, I want users to be able to kill it, and thus far that looks like a simple system call:

```
subprocess.run('monit stop app')
```

This way the automatic restart does not kick in with the next check - it stops and becomes unmonitored.

But even after this, I would like it to restart sometime at night, so there is no dependence on users forgetting to restart. How would I go about adding a cron  expression to do this, without losing the normal check each minute?

The relevant part of config at the moment is just:

```
check process app with pidfile /var/run/app.pid
start program = "/proj/folder/app/launchscript.sh start"
stop program = "/proj/folder/app/launchscript.sh stop"
# and with pseudocode I would like something like 
if app is stopped or not monitored at 0 3 * * * then start
```

Is this possible? If not I can make a crontab entry from the app that issues a monit start, but I'd rather stick to monit.

Comment: What I did in the end was issue a monit start piped to the at command:
`monit start app | at 3 am tomorrow`